# Plone/Workflow- Why is portal_workflow tool's getStatusOf returning None?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I'm trying to get the workflow state of a dexterity content type (my.product.my_object)

My workflow 'my_object_workflow' has three states:
draft
pending_approval
approved

In my browserview, I am trying to get the status of my_objects.
I query portal_catalog for my_objects.

```
my_objects = api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_catalog').searchResults(
                                           {'portal_type':'my.product.my_object',
                                             ...
                                           })
```

I get the brains and then iterate through the list and attempt to print the state with the portal_workflow tool.:

```
wf_tool = api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_workflow')

for m_obj in my_objects:
    print wf_tool.getStatusOf('my_object_workflow',m_obj.getObject())
```

Unfortunately, rather than printing the state of the object, it prints None instead.

I could use m_obj['review_state'] instead since m_obj is a brain, but I'd prefer to use the portal_workflow tool.

What could cause this to happen?  Am I misunderstand what getStatusOf is actually for?

I am using Plone 4.3

Comment: I apologize but I figured out that during my iteration, I was using the wrong object.  May I delete this question?  I don't believe it would serve any purpose.

Comment: Nvm, a lengthy answer was provided for when this issue could arise.

Comment: You may delete it, but I just wrote an answer, because it's easy possible to get the issues you had by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to know what `getStatusOf`is actually doing.
There are several possible cases to get `None` if `getStatusOf` is called.

First take a look at the implementation (`Products.CMFCore.WorkflowTool`):

```
def getStatusOf(self, wf_id, ob):
    """ Get the last element of a workflow history for a given workflow.
    """
    wfh = self.getHistoryOf(wf_id, ob)
    if wfh:
        return wfh[-1]
    return None

def getHistoryOf(self, wf_id, ob):
    """ Get the history of an object for a given workflow.
    """
    if hasattr(aq_base(ob), 'workflow_history'):
        wfh = ob.workflow_history
        return wfh.get(wf_id, None)
    return ()
```

`getStatusOf` gets the last entry of list stored in the `workflow_history` attribute.

The `workflow_history` is a persistent Dict:

- The keys are the workflow id's - In your case `my_object_workflow`
- The values are the workflow transitions (List of transitions)

---

**Why your brain metadata has the wrong value?**

Usually this happens if you manipulate/change the workflow and you forget to update the catalog.

---

**Why calling `getStatusOf` is None?**

This usually happens if you change the workflow and the `workflow_history` storage for the new workflow is empty or not yet initialized.

---

**How can I avoid this problem if I change the workflow configuration for my type?**

IMHO this is not an easy task. You need to be avare of several things.

I personally use `ftw.upgrade` to introduce a new workflow for my type.

Go thru the [Workflow Chain Updater](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.upgrade#workflow-chain-updater) section of Readme or check out the [implementation](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.upgrade/blob/master/ftw/upgrade/workflow.py#L12)

You have to do the following steps manually or use ftw.upgrade if you have changed the workflow for your type:

- Set state of every object to the initial state of the new workflow
- Migrate the workflow history from the old to the new workflow
- If you remove the workflow from a specific type you need to reset the permissions manually for each affected object.
- Keep the catalog up to date.

Comment: Thankyou for providing an in depth answer.  This will cover any issues I may have in the future with getting the status of a workflow.  I appreciate it.